# PlayerPrefsException on Windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3d game build on Windows width the 5.3.4 version. I get this error

> PlayerPrefsException: Could not store preference value at
>   UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString (System.String key, System.String
>   value) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   SlotManager+c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00000] in
>   :0  (Filename:  Line: -1)

Hay Im doing is just a regular PlayerPrefs.SetString. According to documentation (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefsException.html) this exception shouldn't appear on Windows platform and I couldn't find any information about this subject. Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Might be a permission problem. Maybe the place where the file should be stored is not accessible or read-only.

Comment: Which Windows are you using?

Comment: @Cress  I tried with another scene and works perfectly. The people who's playing the game says that the first time, it works fine. The second times, it gets the exception.

Comment: @StevenMills windows 7 and 8

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, did you ever resolve it?